# usage of although

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

I am trying to learn how to use *although*.

Is the sentence below correct?

> **Although**, low vegetation being portrayed as buildings is restricted by the elevation constraint, some vegetation patches misguided small building detection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly, but not quite.

*Although* uses the pattern "Although X, Y", where Y contrasts X, for example:

> **Although** I wanted to eat some cake, all the cake had already been eaten.
>
> **Although** I brought my umbrella with me to work, it didn't rain the whole day.

Consequently we can notice a few minor errors with your sentence.

Firstly, *Although* is not a clause in itself, so we should remove the comma that's immediately after it in your sentence.

Secondly, the clause "some vegetation patches misguided small building detection" doesn't really make any sense. If we chose a different clause that makes sense and contrasts the first clause, such as "some vegetation patches still look like small buildings", we can make a sentence such as the following:

> **Although** low vegetation being portrayed as buildings is restricted by the elevation constraint, **some vegetation patches still look like small buildings**.

Comment: “Some vegetation patches misguided small building detection” merely means that patches of vegetation misled the small-building-detection program.

Answer (score 1):

If one follows the clause pattern of the original sentence, a possibility could be

> **However,** low vegetation being portrayed as buildings is restricted by the elevation constraint, **so/therefore** some vegetation patches misguided small building detection.

but I think more context is needed to decide how to best phrase the statement.

Comment: *However* usually goes with the contrasting clause (*although* goes with the clause to be contrasted), so if you were to replace *although* with *however* in the OP's sentence, it would go "Low vegetation being portrayed as buildings is restricted by the elevation constraint, **however** some vegetation patches misguided small building detection."

Comment: @ Matt When I wrote this I was thinking there was a previous sentence, and this statement contrasted it, so I used "However". As in "The imaging system generally identifies surface features accurately. However, low vegetation...". Maybe I read too much into it.